# ExtJS 4 uploading files (using CodeIgniter for backend)

Tags: extjs, codeigniter-2

I have the standard upload file form from the ExtJS documentations, I create `form.Panel` with with `xtype:filefield` and an `open` and `Submit` button. And as it is by default when I click Open the browser window is opened and I can choose a file, and then Submit it for saving. But now I\m asked to bypass this and leave only a button with name `Open` directly on the toolbar and clicking it to open directly the browser window. I don't know even if this is possible and how to do it.

thanks

Leron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am I understanding this correctly? You need to have a just single button on the page - user clicks button, gets file open dialog and when he presses 'OK' on that dialog form is submitted?

Take a look at the second sample 'Button only'
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/form/file-upload.html

Comment: Hmm, almost like this. I know I haven't explain it right, but gonna try with this one. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to listen to the filefield.[change](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.File-event-change) event, and submit your form when that fires. Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/62gmq/3/